# Find skewness and kurtosis of a bivariate scatterplot

Tags: multivariate-analysis, bivariate, scatterplot

I was reading [this paper](https://rdcu.be/chyZJ) in the medical field which proposes a method using two radiological parameters in order to distinguish benign and malignant lesions. In their paper the Authors show this plot

[image]

They show after in the results that skewness and kurtosis of these lesions is different between benign and malignant lesions. I'm wondering how the calculations are performed. Are they referring to Mardia's multivariate skewness and kurtosis? Are there any methods to calculate in R bivariate skewness and kurtosis other than Mardia's?